# Multiple dlopen and RTLD_NEXT

Tags: c, dlopen, dlsym

I have an executable (1) with two shared objects (2 and 3) opened using dlopen(..., RTLD_GLOBAL). All files include the symbol func().

If I use dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, ...) in 1 looking for the next func() symbol, the 2 symbol is returned. But, if in 2 I use dlsym(RTLD_NEXT) again, no symbol is found. I thought that 3 symbol would be returned.

What is the meaning of this?

**Update**: adding an example

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef void (*next_t) (void);
static char *name[] = { "next" };
static char  path[1024];
static next_t linc;

static void dlnext_open(int i)
{
    sprintf(path, "./lib%d.so", i);
    fprintf(stderr, "loading %d\n", i);
    void *handler = dlopen(path, RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NOW);
    return;
}

int next()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "NEXT %d\n", NUM);

    #ifdef DLNUM1
    dlnext_open(DLNUM1);
    #endif
    #ifdef DLNUM2
    dlnext_open(DLNUM2);
    #endif

    linc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, name[0]);

    if (linc != NULL) { 
        linc();
        fprintf(stderr, "returning to %d\n", NUM);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "no next\n");
    }
}

#if NUM == 1
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    next();
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

And the make/exec:

```
gcc -O0 -shared -fPIC -o lib3.so 1.c -DNUM=3
gcc -O0 -shared -fPIC -o lib2.so 1.c -DNUM=2
gcc -O0 -o 1 1.c -ldl -DNUM=1 -DDLNUM1=2 -DDLNUM2=3
./1
```

The result:

```
NEXT 1
loading 2
loading 3
NEXT 2
no next
returning to 1
```

Comment: Write simple snippets of code to illustrate the issue (a [mre]), it's not clear which program is doing what and how. Also, show how you are compiling.

Comment: I think it means you are walking on thin ice, I mean using this RTLD_NEXT option won't give you a reliable solution (whatever the problem is).